# Rails While Loop: Can't load a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, while-loop, activeadmin, reify

Good morning folks.  In a model of mine, I created a method for displaying a row. 
The page wasn't working cause next and reify methods we're undefined , 
so I put a try on them. But the page doesn't load and is displaying this error on browser. "504 Gateway Time-out"

```
v = self.versions.first
 if v.present?
 while v.try(:reify).try(:reason).try(:name).blank? do
    v = v.try(:next)
  end
  v.reify.try(:reason).try(:name)
end
```

What do you recommend me to make this code much cleaner and to prevent it for long page loading again ?

Comment: Have you considered implementing those methods?

Comment: Looks like some kind of infinite loop if you are getting gateway timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is effectively same as below after first iteration of loop, which is a infinite loop

```
while nil.try(:reify).try(:reason).try(:name).blank? # always true
   # ...
end
```

Your web server gives up while waiting for loop to terminate and hence reports - `504 - Gateway timeout` to user/browser.

---

[`try`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#try) allows you to invoke a method on a `nil` objects without throwing any exception - if object was `nil` or if method was not implemented, it will return `nil`.

So, lets say `v` was some object that did not implement `reify` method, then, `v.try(:reify)` will be `nil`

```
 v = "Ruby"
 v = v.try(:reify)
 #=> nil
 v = v.try(:next)
 #=> nil
 v.try(:reify).try(:reason).try(:name).blank?
 #=> true
```

---

Only solution for your problem is to ensure that your loop terminates.

Comment: So it should look this now,right?      'v = self.versions.first
    if v.present?
     while v.try(:reify).try(:reason).try(:name).blank? do
      v = v.try(:next)
      end
    v.try(:reify).try(:reason).try(:name).blank?
    end'

Comment: @RailsCoder. Its hard to say without looking at exact value of `self.versions.first`.  You will have to debug by inspecting its value.